# jQuery .click() .show() function issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Could anyone please let me know what i'm doing wrong.
I have:

```
//My HTML
    <div>
      <ul>
         <li id="test"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
            <ul class="list-in-list">
               <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
         <li><a href="#">Main Item 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Main Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

//My CSS
    .list-in-list {
    display:none;
    }

//My jQuery

   $(document).ready(function() {

         $('#test').click(function() {
           alert("hello");
           });
    });
```

My final goal is to show that none displayed content if you press a list item, so that it expands neatly. However, i can't seem to get that alert() appearing in any way. Should i use an id for all list items in the main list, or is it enough with a class?

/W

Comment: Alert is working perfectly in you code http://jsfiddle.net/qLSrG/, you probably forgot to add jquery to your project.

Comment: The alert has to work, the code is good. Have you included jQuery in your site?

Comment: It is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/hjLJH/

Comment: show complete html code with imported js files

Comment: there's no problem in the code. Did it show any error? try this 
           $('#test').click(function() {
           $('.list-in-list').toggle();
           });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add .next function to show next ul for any li curreny click by user. you have to change id test to one class name to make effect in all click of main li

HTML would be like

```
 <div>
  <ul>
     <li class="main"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a></li>
        <ul class="list-in-list">
           <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
     <li class="main" ><a href="#">Main Item 2</a></li>

      <ul class="list-in-list">
           <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
     <li class="main"><a href="#">Main Item 3</a></li>

      <ul class="list-in-list">
           <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and JQuery function is below

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     $('.main').click(function() {                
         $(this).next(".list-in-list").slideToggle();             
       });
});
```

for detail you can check [link](http://jsfiddle.net/liyakat/7uvuz/1/)

Comment: This doesn't answer your question. This answers comments made to your question. As you've accepted this answer you should change your question to reflect the comments to make it easier for users who may come here through a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine I do believe you have not included Jquery on your page - or maybe the path to it is not valid. Check your network tab to see if you get an http error retrieving jquery.

You can show the hidden li by doing the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function(e) {
        $(this).find('.list-in-list').show();
    });
});
```

Your code works fine:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rDHEV/)

In this case classes would be better than ids because Id's have to be unique on your page. You can use classes like in the demo below by adding a class to your outer li elements. Just change the binding from *#test* to whatever class you give your li elements.

```
$('.clickAbleLi').click(function(e) {
   $(this).find('.list-in-list').show();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rDHEV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

> Should i use an id for all list items in the main list, or is it enough with a class?

IDs are **unique**. Your JavaScript code will not work properly if you have multiple identical IDs. If you're planning on adding a similar attribute to all of your list items you'd use a class in this case (and reference it with `.` instead of `#`). In this case you'd call the click function using:

```
$('li.myClass').click(...);
```

If you only have one list, however, you can simply add the ID to the `ul` and use the click function as:

```
$('ul#myId > li').click(...);
```

Note that it would be marginally quicker with the classes in this case.

You'd then reference your *inner* `ul` using:

```
$('li.myClass > ul.list-in-list');
```

Or, depending on which of the above you went with:

```
$('ul#myId > li > ul.list-in-list');
```

(You'd use `>` here to select only the direct child. If you used `ul#myId li` you'd also be selecting the `li` elements which belong to any *inner* `ul`)

Answer (score 0):

You close your `</li>` tag before your "list-in-list". You should close your `</li>` tag after your inside list ;) Like this :

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li id="test"><a href="#">Main Item 1</a>
        <ul class="list-in-list">
           <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Main Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Main Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It sholud work but Try moving the ID attribute to the A instead of LI if you experience problems